# How to get select option data in next input element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get select option data attribute value in input value with option change. I tried the following its working with first tr but not working on select when i add another tr.

```js
var i=$('table tr').length;
    $("#add").on('click',function(){
     html = '<tr>';
     html += '<td><select  class="fruits"> <option value="Apple" data-val="3">Apple</option>  <option value="Orange" data-val="8">Orange</option> <option value="Banana" data-val="7">Banana</option> </select> <input type="text" class="fet"></td>';
     html += '</tr>';
     $('table').append(html);
     i++;
    });

$('.fruits').on('change', function() { 
    $(this).next().val($("option:selected",this).data('val')); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table>
       <tr>
          <td>
             <select  class="fruits">
                <option value="Apple" data-val="3">Apple</option>
                <option value="Orange" data-val="8">Orange</option>
                <option value="Banana" data-val="7">Banana</option>
             </select>
          <input type="text" class="fet">
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
    </table>
    <button type="button" id="add"> Add </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your

```
$('.fruits').on('change', function() { 
   $(this).next().val($("option:selected",this).data('val')); 
});
```

To

```
$(document).on('change', '.fruits', function() { 
    $(this).next().val($("option:selected",this).data('val')); 
});
```

What happens is,

When your code executed `jquery` only binds events to the element those are present in DOM.

So when you are dynamically adding the elements, events are not binded.

So instead on binding `change` event on `.fruits` bind it to `document`. So that event should be binded with the dynamically added elements

```js
var i=$('table tr').length;
    $("#add").on('click',function(){
     html = '<tr>';
     html += '<td><select  class="fruits"> <option value="Apple" data-val="3">Apple</option>  <option value="Orange" data-val="8">Orange</option> <option value="Banana" data-val="7">Banana</option> </select> <input type="text" class="fet"></td>';
     html += '</tr>';
     $('table').append(html);
     i++;
    });

$(document).on('change', '.fruits', function() { 
    $(this).next().val($("option:selected",this).data('val')); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table>
       <tr>
          <td>
             <select  class="fruits">
                <option value="Apple" data-val="3">Apple</option>
                <option value="Orange" data-val="8">Orange</option>
                <option value="Banana" data-val="7">Banana</option>
             </select>
          <input type="text" class="fet">
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
    </table>
    <button type="button" id="add"> Add </button>
```